# Escape Sequence vs. Whitespace Character (\s)

Tags: java, escaping, whitespace, sequences

Are escape sequences and whitespace characters the same thing? I'm not sure what else to write here but Stackoverflow said the first sentence is not enough so I'm typing this second sentence for no reason at all but that so this post will go through.

Comment: No, they are not the same thing. See [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) and [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). Also `\s` only means whitespace in a regular expression. Are you asking about regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few escape sequences specified in `Java`, of which `\s` is not part. The `\s` is recognized as whitespace in regular expressions, where it is a predefined character class.

Check the following sections from the Java Tutorial:

- [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)
- [Predefined Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Comment: Actually \s is a valid escape sequence according to JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7